# I can't log into my iChat

Tags: icloud, ichat

After iChat is open, I click the menu named 'iChat', inside it says "log into pancake44@me.com" (which is my Apple ID). I've clicked on that item but nothing else prompts me for a password afterwards.

The buddy list still says 'Disconnected'. I am using Leopard (10.5.8). I have changed my password before, but I'm never prompted to actually log in and update it.

Answer (score 1):

I might not be understanding your problem correctly, but in the iChat menu, try selecting **Preferences**. From there, click on the **Accounts** tab. If you click on your account, there is a place to enter (and store) your password. Try entering your correct password there.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you mentioned it just says "Disconnected", can you *click* that and perhaps change your status to something else? That would trigger it to try and connect.